# How can I get SELinux to allow runc to transition to container_t?

Tags: fedora, selinux

I am referencing [this page](https://github.com/AFLplusplus/AFLplusplus/blob/stable/docs/INSTALL.md) and following these simple instructions on Fedora 36:

```
docker pull aflplusplus/aflplusplus:
docker run -ti -v /location/of/your/target:/src aflplusplus/aflplusplus
```

However, I get this SELinux error:

```
SELinux is preventing runc:[2:INIT] from using the transition access on a process.

*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

If you believe that runc:[2:INIT] should be allowed transition access on processes labeled container_t by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'runc:[2:INIT]' --raw | audit2allow -M my-runc2INIT
# semodule -X 300 -i my-runc2INIT.pp

Additional Information:
Source Context                system_u:system_r:unconfined_service_t:s0
Target Context                system_u:system_r:container_t:s0:c149,c848
Target Objects                /usr/bin/bash [ process ]
Source                        runc:[2:INIT]
Source Path                   runc:[2:INIT]
Port                          <Unknown>
Host                          localhost.localdomain
Source RPM Packages           
Target RPM Packages           bash-5.2.15-1.fc36.x86_64
SELinux Policy RPM            selinux-policy-targeted-36.17-1.fc36.noarch
Local Policy RPM              selinux-policy-targeted-36.17-1.fc36.noarch
Selinux Enabled               True
Policy Type                   targeted
Enforcing Mode                Enforcing
Host Name                     localhost.localdomain
Platform                      Linux localhost.localdomain 6.1.13-100.fc36.x86_64
                              #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Feb 22 18:13:06 UTC
                              2023 x86_64 x86_64
Alert Count                   1
First Seen                    2023-07-23 01:36:16 PDT
Last Seen                     2023-07-23 01:36:16 PDT
Local ID                      c389e11d-1f68-4433-b24e-27b54adbb8a9

Raw Audit Messages
type=AVC msg=audit(1690101376.101:6745): avc:  denied  { transition } for  pid=2847426 comm="runc:[2:INIT]" path="/usr/bin/bash" dev="overlay" ino=2172597 scontext=system_u:system_r:unconfined_service_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:container_t:s0:c149,c848 tclass=process permissive=0


Hash: runc:[2:INIT],unconfined_service_t,container_t,process,transition
```

How can I permit this action? I have tried the following:

```
sudo semanage fcontext -a -t container_t "/usr/bin/runc"
sudo semanage fcontext -a -t container_t "/usr/bin/bash"
```

I have also tried the temporary fix in the error message, which failed with:

```
Failed to resolve allow statement at /var/lib/selinux/targeted/tmp/modules/200/container/cil:1245
Failed to resolve AST
semodule:  Failed!
```

The semanage commands also fail and give me:

```
ValueError: Type container_t is invalid, must be a file or device type
```

I have run the command `rpm -qa|grep selinux|sort` which outputs:

```
container-selinux-2.199.0-1.fc36.noarch
flatpak-selinux-1.12.7-5.fc36.noarch
libselinux-3.3-4.fc36.x86_64
libselinux-devel-3.3-4.fc36.x86_64
libselinux-utils-3.3-4.fc36.x86_64
python3-libselinux-3.3-4.fc36.x86_64
rpm-plugin-selinux-4.17.1-3.fc36.x86_64
selinux-policy-36.17-1.fc36.noarch
selinux-policy-targeted-36.17-1.fc36.noarch
snapd-selinux-2.57.6-2.fc36.noarch
tpm2-abrmd-selinux-2.3.1-5.fc36.noarch
```

Comment: You are missing `fcontext` as argument to `semanage`. Furthermore, the syntax is `'/path/to/dir(/.*)?'`. After that you need to run `restorecon -vvRF /path/to/dir`

Comment: @ValentinBajrami are you saying that I have to add this transition access for *everything in the /usr/bin/ directory?*

Comment: The endian, no, I provided a general idea on how fcontext works. So you can add fcontext for the binaries you want, not  entire dir

Comment: Different versions of Docker can be installed on Fedora, each with its own peculiarities regarding SELinux. For example, most implementations of Docker on an SELinux system require the `container-selinux` RPM package (sometimes called `docker-selinux`). These packages contain the correct policies for running Docker with SELinux enabled. Can you run `rpm -qa|grep selinux|sort` and put the output in your question?

Comment: @Edward sure I've updated it with the requested information.

Answer (score -1):

The system alreadu told you how to allow the transition from `unconfined_service_t` to `container_t`. See this part of the message you quoted:

```
Do allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'runc:[2:INIT]' --raw | audit2allow -M my-runc2INIT
# semodule -X 300 -i my-runc2INIT.pp
```

The `#` at the beginning indicates the commands should be executed as root. It is not a part of the command; it just stands for the root command prompt.
If you just copy & paste the whole lines as commands, the shell will interpret `#` as a comment symbol, and will do nothing at all.

The first command, `ausearch -c 'runc:[2:INIT]' --raw | audit2allow -M my-runc2INIT` finds the exact event in your audit logs and feeds it to `audit2allow`, which will create a `my-runc2INIT` SELinux rule module (a `my-runc2INIT.pp` file).

The second command will install the rule module, to make it take effect.

If you wish to remove the custom rule later, `semodule -r my-runc2INIT` should do that.

Comment: As stated above, those commands were run and they produced the error message listed in the question: `[root@localhost]# ausearch -c 'runc:[2:INIT]' --raw | audit2allow -M my-runc2INIT
******************** IMPORTANT ***********************
To make this policy package active, execute:

semodule -i my-runc2INIT.pp

[root@localhost]# semodule -i my-runc2INIT.pp
Failed to resolve allow statement at /var/lib/selinux/targeted/tmp/modules/200/container/cil:1245
Failed to resolve AST
semodule:  Failed!` The # was not issued in the command, and I tried both `sudo` and full root shown above.

Comment: The original message suggested to run the `semodule` command with the `-X 300` option, but here it looks like you ran it without that. It might or might not make a difference, though...

Comment: Did the first command also create a `my-runc2INIT.te` file?  What does it contain (it should be a text file)?

Comment: The same result occurs with -X 300 too. And yes it did: `module my-runc2INIT 1.0;

require {
        type container_t;
        type unconfined_service_t;
        class process transition;
}

#============= unconfined_service_t ==============
allow unconfined_service_t container_t:process transition;
`